# How to fix laravel 404 NotFoundHttpException Error?

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I am using this laravel package called yajra datables to create a data table for my app. But I am getting this error whenever I reload the page. After a few reloads the table gets loaded. However, page keeps throwing me ajax errors every time I use the search option.

[image: error]

I have searched the internet for every possible solution, but none of them seemed to work.

Below is my code:

**Index.blade**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jobsTable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('activity.index') }}",
        dom: "B" + /* Buttons */
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l>" + /* Length changing input control */
            "<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>>" + /* Filtering Input */
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" + /* The Table! + Processing Display Element*/
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i>" + /* Table Information Summary */
                        "<'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>" , /* Pagination Control*/
        columns:[
            /* 1 */ {data: 'id' , name: 'id', visible: false },
            /* 0 */ {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false },
            /* 1 */ {data: 'job_id' , name: 'job_id' },
            /* 2 */ {data: 'type' , name: 'type' },
            /* 3 */ {data: 'job_no' , name: 'job_no' },
            /* 4 */ {data: 'deal_no' , name: 'deal_no' },
            /* 5 */ {data: 'cyc_no' , name: 'cyc_no' },
            /* 6 */ {data: 'deal_name' , name: 'deal_name' },
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        if (request()->ajax()) {

            $jobs = Job::all();

            return DataTables::of($jobs)
                ->addColumn('action', function ($jobs) {
                    $button = '<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">';
                    $button .= '<a href="/activity/' . $jobs->id . '/edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>';
                    $button .= '<button type="button" name="deleteButton" id="' . $jobs->id . '" data-jobcycid="' . $jobs->job_no . ' | ' . $jobs->cyc_no . '" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs deleteButton"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>&nbsp;Delete</button>';
                    $button .= '</div>';
                    return $button;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])

                ->setRowID(function ($jobs) {
                    return $jobs->id;
                })
                ->make(true);
        }

        return view('activity.index');
    }
```

**Routes**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.roles']], function () {

    /*Side bar menu Routes*/
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@dashb')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/profile', 'HomeController@profile')->name('profile');

    /*Activity Routes*/
    Route::resource('/activity', 'JobController');
    // Route::get('/activity', 'JobController@getIndex')->name('activity.index');

    /*Activity Sub Routes*/
    Route::get('/jobEditCancel', 'JobController@jobEditCancel')->name('jobEditCancel');
    Route::get('/jobAddCancel', 'JobController@jobAddCancel')->name('jobAddCancel');



    // Route::get('/activity', 'JobController@index')->name('activity.index');
    // Route::delete('/activity/destroy/{id}', 'JobController@destroy')->name('activity.destroy');

    /*FPBlog Routes*/
    Route::resource('fpblog', 'PostController');
    Route::get('/postEditCancel', 'PostController@postEditCancel')->name('postEditCancel');
    Route::get('/blogManager', 'PostController@blogManager')->name('blogManager');
});
```

Comment: can you run (php artisan route:list) command and share with us the results?

Comment: Hi @AhmedAtoui. Please refer below link. Really appreciate your help.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/XeDrYf42TwQn1U1v5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you each and every one of you who have tried your best to support me to solve this problem. However, after so many searches for the answer, I have figured it it out.

Apparently my URI is far too long. I was able to understand this after moving my development environment to laravel Homestead.

I have followed the steps on this blog to shorten the url. And it solved all the issues:

[DataTables and Long URL](https://yajrabox.com/blog/datatables-and-long-url)

Once again thank you very much for anyone who has provided their opinion. I hope this post will be useful to someone who is trying to create data tables which have high column counts.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `url: "{{ route('activity.index') }}"` yet in your route file you commented the alias.

You can put alias for resource routes like this

```php
/*Activity Routes*/
Route::resource('activity', 'JobController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'activity.index',
        'create' => 'activity.create',
        'store' => 'activity.store',
        'show' => 'activity.show',
        'edit' => 'activity.edit',
        'update' => 'activity.update',
        'destroy' => 'activity.destoy'
    ],
]);
```

and this should work for your case in using the alias `activity.index` in the blade.

For why you're better off without `resource` ? it's mostly a point of view.
When you declare each route yourself, you have more control on the routes:

- middleware per route possible
- clear which route is valid without having to check the controller
- name the methods/routes as you want
- ...etc

Comment: Hi @N69S. Really appreciate your interest in this matter.

I did that while trying to debug this. It was like that when this issue came in. Can't I use it as a resource route? What is your recommendation?

Comment: @Supunsam i've edited my answer to give you a full response.

Comment: Thank you very much @N69S..Your advice is very educative. I am fairly new to laravel and these tips mean a lot.

However, I applied your routes but the issue remains the same. maybe this has something to do with my developing environment. I use XAMPP. I do not use Laravel Homestead or anything of that sort.

Comment: @Supunsam check your `.env` file, you will see `APP_URL`, set it to `http://localhost:8000` (with port) and check if that fixes your issue. if you still have an issue, check how to set up vhost on XAMPP to set a domain without port. But before that run `php artisan route:list` to check the declared routes in your project.

Comment: @Supunsam have you advanced on your issue ?

Comment: Hi @N69S.

I found out what the issue is. Obviously I had to change my development environment to Homestead to get more clarity of the error. Apparently It was ue to extremely long URL generated by the high column count of my data table. I have posted the answer below.